# Why doesnt my mesh follow my bones the way i want? (Video)

Tags: mesh, armature, bones

I am new to Blender and in the video below you will see a simple water creature mesh with an armature connected to it. The bones of the armature are placed inside the arms and body of the creature.

The body bone seems to deform the mesh ok, but when i move any of the arm bones the whole mesh is affected in a way thats not optimal i think... The end goal is to have each arm bone only move the mesh arm its placed inside of.

Is there any solution to this?

https://youtu.be/MSDIy4V8DFM

Comment: You might need to specify how vertices weight is assign to your armature, with picture using upload tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear the parenting (Alt P), then select the mesh, in edit mode select all, and choose "recalculate normals", then in object mode apply (Ctrl A) rot and scale to both mesh and armature, then redo the parenting (Ctrl P) choosing "Automatic weight".

Comment: It worked! =D Thank you so much @josh sanfelici

Comment: You're welcome, please mark the answer as "accepted".